# Linking result from searching in database, to another page

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

For a school project, I have to make a webshop with PHP and use a database to search for your products, I have the code to display the results, however, I want to make a link, so that when you click on one of the search results, you go to that product's page.

I've tried looking online but I couldn't seem to find it anywhere, that's why I'm posting this question.

```
$sql = "SELECT ProductID, ProductTags, ProductName FROM producttabel";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo '<div class="allepccskop">';
    echo "Onze producten: " . "<br>";
    echo '</div>';
    
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div class="allepccs">';
    echo $row["ProductName"]. "<br>";
    echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: make a php file for single product. And get product id or something with get request in this file. And get product details then show with this id. (sql where clause)

Comment: What exactly _is_ your question?  What is stopping you from doing what you want?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PatrickQ well, i really do not know what to do and i couldnt find my problem online, but i will rephrase my question:
In the code it says: $row["productname"] . 
i want to make an IF statement like:
IF     $row["productname"] =  product 2 {

href:product2.php

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make a link when you click on one of the search results, you go to that product's page.

To make a link to a product page, you need to use html [a tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp), just wrap it around your product name like this:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?id=' . $row["ProductID"] . '">' . $row["ProductName"]. "</a><br>";
```

The `href` attribute contains your php file name (e.g. index.php) and a `GET` parameter `id` to send the product id to the php page.

**Full example:**

Assuming you want to extend your code to display a single product when a product id (`ProductID`) is provided or all products otherwise.

This is a simple example how you could extend your code, look at the comments:

```
<?php

// take id from the request, otherwise set default to null
$productId = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;

// when we have an id in the url, then we display a product page
if (!is_null($productId)) {

    $sql = 'SELECT ProductID, ProductTags, ProductName FROM producttabel WHERE ProductID = ' . $productId;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result && $result->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $result->free(); // free result set

        // output data of each row
        echo '<div class="allepccskop">';
        echo "Product page: #" . $productId . "<br>";
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="allepccs">';
        echo $row["ProductName"]. "<br>";
        echo '</div>';

    } else {
        echo "Product not found";
    }

// otherwise we show All products page
} else {

    // your code

    $sql = 'SELECT ProductID, ProductTags, ProductName FROM producttabel';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo '<div class="allepccskop">';
        echo "Onze producten: " . "<br>";
        echo '</div>';

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<div class="allepccs">';
            echo '<a href="index.php?id=' . $row["ProductID"] . '">' . $row["ProductName"]. "</a><br>"; 
            echo '</div>';
        }
        $result->free(); // free result set
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

}
```